# display data using bean and servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I'm still learning developing webapps. I came across this tutorial.

EmpBean.java

```
package form;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class EmpBean {

public List dataList(){
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
           while(rs.next()){
               list.add(rs.getString("name"));
               list.add(rs.getString("address"));
               list.add(rs.getString("contactNo"));
               list.add(rs.getString("email"));

}
}
catch(Exception e){}
return list;

}
}
```

BeanInServlet.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class BeanInServlet extends HttpServlet{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
        form.EmpBean p = new form.EmpBean();
        List list=p.dataList();

        req.setAttribute("data", list);
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/beandata.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

beandata.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
<body> 
<table border="1" width="303">
<tr>
<td width="119"><b>Name</b></td>
<td width="168"><b>Address</b></td>
<td width="119"><b>Contact no</b></td>
<td width="168"><b>Email</b></td>
</tr>
<%Iterator itr;%>
<% List data= (List)request.getAttribute("data");
for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
%>
<tr>
<td width="119"><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td width="168"><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td width="168"><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td width="168"><%=itr.next()%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this with netbeans and it works.. However I wonder if JSTL can be use to present the data (View).

Comment: an example of this with jdbc connection would be very helpful... thanks to all

Comment: An example of JDBC connection? You're using the same with JDBC connection.

Comment: The answer is "yes". Just read another tutorial which covers JSTL.

Comment: sorry the for the confusion.. only the how this can be displayed using jstl

Comment: @toink: the very first thing to take into acount, is that your list contains every single value o every single record at the very same level. This is hard to handle, and error prone. Think about creating a VO class and use it to store the data of every element and add them to the list.

Comment: @toink: Also (and maybe more important), the JDBC code at the EmpBean class is going to lock down your database for too many connections open, as you open a connection, an statement, and get a resultset for you query, but never close any of them. You should close them all at a finally block.

Comment: thanks guys... I'm learning a lot from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the c:foreach is what you'd be looking for.  Though this is of course assuming that your list is in multiples of 4.  This is done from memory, so i make no guarantee there won't be syntax errors.

```
<table>
<c:foreach var="item" varStatus="status" items="${requestScope.data}">
 <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${status.index % 4 == 0}">
   <tr>
   <td width="119"><c:out value="${item}" /></td>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
   <td width="168"><c:out value="${item}" /></td>
  </c:otherwise>   
 </c:choose>
 <c:if test="${status.index % 4 == 3}">
  </tr>
 </c:if>
</c:foreach>
</table>
```